# Why the class name start with number?

Tags: java

In the Hadoop java client jar,find some class name start with number in  `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

```
 return new 5(this, f, recursive); //line 802
 return new 4(this, f, filter);  //line 794
```

Comment: Is this decompiled code? Could it be that the decompiler has changed `SomeClass$4` to `4`?

Comment: A digit as first character of an identifier is syntactically illegal in Java. Identifiers must start with a letter, underscore or dollar sign, so this is probably decompiled or obfuscated code.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah,you are right,tried another decompiler,the decompile code is correct.

Comment: @MrLou why not just look at the original source code? Hadoop is open source, after all.

Comment: I thought i read source code,figuring why maven did not download the source jar.